# Why is the performance of `while` said to be slower than `for` when iterating over an array?

Tags: performance, rust

The second edition of *The Rust Programming Language* [states the following](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-05-control-flow.html#looping-through-a-collection-with-for) about while loops for iterating over an array:

```
fn main() {
    let a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
    let mut index = 0;

    while index < 5 {
        println!("the value is: {}", a[index]);

        index = index + 1;
    }
}
```

> [...] It’s also slow, because the compiler adds runtime code to perform the conditional check on every element on every iteration through the loop.
>
> As a more efficient alternative, you can use a for loop and execute some code for each item in a collection.

```
fn main() {
    let a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

    for element in a.iter() {
        println!("the value is: {}", element);
    }
}
```

In C++ I would expect a compiler/optimizer to produce something with equivalent run-time performance.

Why is this not the case in Rust?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In C++ I would expect a compiler/optimizer to produce something with equivalent run-time performance.

Because the two snippets are *not* equivalent. The use of `a[i]` in Rust maps to `a.at(i)` and the use of `unsafe { a.get_unchecked(i) }` in Rust maps to `a[i]` in C++.

That is, C++ does *not* perform bounds-checking by default, which is how you get **buffer overflows**.

> Why is this not the case in Rust?

Rust, when not using the `unsafe` keyword, should be memory safe. In many situations this is achieved by compile-time checks, but bounds checking require runtime checks in general.

This does not mean that the `while` case will always be slower: it just means that you submit yourself to the whims of the optimizer, and sometimes it lets you down (eliminating bounds-checks is a hard problem).

Thus, the recommendation is to use idioms which are known to optimize well.